# C++ read() returns unformatted binary data

Tags: c++, binary, file-handling

I have a sample file which reads contents from a file. The content is in an unreadable format as shown below. When I use the read() function and cout the variable, it returns the same binary data instead of showing normal text. How to read the contents in a humanly readable format?

Here are the contents of the file (upon using the write() function) I'm reading :

`LÀ                 ³                L¹ R`

Here is the reading code :

```
void readBinary(){
    ifstream inputFile("flights.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);

    char buffer[100];

    inputFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    if(inputFile.is_open()){

        inputFile.read((char *)&buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++){
            cout << buffer[i];
        }

    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```

Here is the code for writing the data :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void inputData();

struct airplaneDetails {

    string airplaneCode;
    int totalRows, seatsInRows, firstSeats, businessSeats, economySeats;

};

int main(){

    inputData();

    return 0;
}

void inputData(){

    ofstream outputFile("flights.dat", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);

    if(!outputFile.is_open()){
        cout << "There was an error opening the file.";
    } else {

        airplaneDetails airplane;

        cout << "Please provide the details below :" << "\n\n";

        cout << "Enter the airplane code : ";
        cin >> airplane.airplaneCode;

        .
        .
        //Assigning values to the variables
        .
        .

        //Put the pointer at the end
        outputFile.seekp(0, ios::end);

        //Write the input data to the binary file
        outputFile.write((char *)&airplane.airplaneCode, sizeof(airplane.airplaneCode));
        outputFile.write((char *)&airplane.totalRows, sizeof(airplane.totalRows));
        outputFile.write((char *)&airplane.seatsInRows, sizeof(airplane.seatsInRows));
        outputFile.write((char *)&airplane.firstSeats, sizeof(airplane.firstSeats));
        outputFile.write((char *)&airplane.businessSeats, sizeof(airplane.businessSeats));
        outputFile.write((char *)&airplane.economySeats, sizeof(airplane.economySeats));

        //Close the file handler
        outputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what you're expecting to see here, could you explain a bit further?

Comment: I'm surprised that you're surprised that when you read a file and print the data you just read, it prints the contents of the file.

Comment: Use `inputFile.gcount()` to determine exactly how many bytes were read from the file.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I'm writing (using the write() function) text into this flights.dat file using another .cpp program. I want to read the contents from that .dat file but in a readable format.

Comment: @immibis Are you implying that the text content is lost? For example, I'm writing the word "Hello" to the file using write(). How can I retrieve "Hello" back with read()?

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim If that's the contents of the file, then it would appear that you have *not* written the word "Hello" to the file.

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim perhaps show us how you wrote the data to the file, it seems that's where the bug might be.

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim It would seem the error resides in how you are writing the file, not how to read it

Comment: @dreamlax I have edited the question with the write function()

Comment: Yup. You can't write a `std::string` like that... well, you *can*, but it won't write anything useful.

Comment: @immibis How to do it properly? Also, other variables are integers.

Comment: Also note that if you are on windows and opened a file in binary mode the `\r\n` translation to `\n` will not happen as in text mode.

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim What do you want the file to contain?

Comment: @immibis Strings and integers line by line. For example : `Hello World\n23\n23`

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim Well then use `<<` not `write`. Same as when you write to `cout`.

Comment: @immibis its a must to use Binary files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to write a string to the binary file. When I used `char airplaneCode[6]` in my structure, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you know *nothing* about the internal representation of objects because their internals is hidden from you (its called "data hiding") so you have no idea what will happen if you dump their binary contents to a file.

You wrote binary out and you are getting binary in.

In particular the `std::string` does **NOT** contain the actual string which is why it is not getting written to your file. The `std::string` merely contains a *pointer* to the string that is stored elsewhere in memory.

Bottom line, don't do binary output unless you control and understand the contents of the objects being written.

You are better off converting everything to text and reading/writing that.

So rather than using `read()` and `write()` use `operator>>` and `operator<<`

```
bool output_details(const airplaneDetails& ad)
{
    std::ofstream ofs("flights.dat"); // text mode

    ofs << ad.airplaneCode << '\n';
    ofs << ad.totalRows << '\n';
    ofs << ad.seatsInRows << '\n';
    ofs << ad.firstSeats << '\n';
    ofs << ad.businessSeats << '\n';
    ofs << ad.economySeats << '\n';

    if(!ofs)
        return false;    

    return true;
}

bool input_details(airplaneDetails& ad)
{
    std::ifstream ifs("flights.dat"); // text mode

    ifs >> ad.airplaneCode;
    ifs >> ad.totalRows;
    ifs >> ad.seatsInRows;
    ifs >> ad.firstSeats;
    ifs >> ad.businessSeats;
    ifs >> ad.economySeats;

    if(!ifs)
        return false;    

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To write text to a file, just write it the same way you'd write to `cout`:

```
outputFile << airplane.airplaneCode << endl;
outputFile << airplane.totalRows << endl;
// and so on
```